# git gc corrupts repository on ubuntu

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I ran git gc in my repository.
After this, I am unable to fetch into it. Getting the following error :

```
git fetch
fatal: Unable to create '<repo_path>/.git/refs/remotes/origin/<path>.lock': Permission denied

git gc
fatal: Unable to create '<repo_path>/.git/refs/remotes/origin/<path>.lock': Permission denied
error: failed to run reflog
```

Please help me understand how can I manually execute garbage collection without corrupting my repos.

Comment: Check permissions in the `.git/refs` hierarchy. Most likely, you ran a Git command as a different user earlier (sudo?), and now you do not have write permission for some of the directories.

Comment: That is not the issue. User is automated, and always the same.

Comment: @somya [Edit] and add the text output of the command `ls -lR <repo_path>/.git`

Comment: `git gc` is not the source of the problem. Running with `sudo` is the source of the problem.